# How can I connect a data set to another when the date is between 2 other dates R

Tags: r, date, match, between

I need to merge two datasets, but the rows have to merge if the date of the one dataset is between two dates of the other one. The first dataset `data` looks like this:

```
      Date   Weight   diff    Loc.nr
2013-01-24     1040      7         2
2013-01-31     1000      7         2
2013-02-07     1185      7         2
2013-02-14      915      7         2
2013-02-21     1090      7         2
2013-03-01     1065      9         2
2013-01-19      500      4         9
2013-01-23     1040      3         9
2013-01-28      415      5         9
2013-01-31      650      3         9
2013-02-04      725      4         9
2013-02-07      450      3         9
2013-02-11      550      4         9
```

The other data set `matches` looks like this:

```
      Date   winning
2013-01-20         1
2013-01-27         0
2013-02-03         1
2013-02-10         0
2013-02-17         1
2013-02-24         0
```

I wrote a code to connect the winning column from `matches` to the data set "data":

```
data$winning <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  for(j in 1:nrow(matches)) {
    if((data$Date[i]-data$diff[i]) < matches$Date[j] & data$Date[i] > matches$Date[j]) {
      data$winning[i] <- matches$winning[j]
    }
  }
}
```

This code takes 3 days to run, is there a faster way to do this?

My expected output is:

```
      Date   Weight   diff    Loc.nr    winning
2013-01-24     1040      7         2          1
2013-01-31     1000      7         2          0
2013-02-07     1185      7         2          1
2013-02-14      915      7         2          0
2013-02-21     1090      7         2          1
2013-03-01     1065      9         2          0
2013-01-19      500      4         9         NA
2013-01-23     1040      3         9         NA
2013-01-28      415      5         9          0
2013-01-31      650      3         9         NA
2013-02-04      725      4         9          1
2013-02-07      450      3         9         NA
2013-02-11      550      4         9          0
```

Comment: Can you explain why `2016-07-01` has `winning=1`? I do not understand the condition when to match.

Comment: Look up "non-equi joins" in `data.table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *non-equi join* as suggested by [Gregor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47220223/how-can-i-connect-a-data-set-to-another-when-the-date-is-between-2-other-dates-r#comment81399896_47220223) you can try something along

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, winning := setDT(matches)[data[, .(upper = Date, lower = Date - diff)], 
                                        on = .(Date < upper, Date > lower)]$winning][]
```

> ```
>           Date Weight diff Loc.nr winning
>  1: 2013-01-24   1040    7      2       1
>  2: 2013-01-31   1000    7      2       0
>  3: 2013-02-07   1185    7      2       1
>  4: 2013-02-14    915    7      2       0
>  5: 2013-02-21   1090    7      2       1
>  6: 2013-03-01   1065    9      2       0
>  7: 2013-01-19    500    4      9      NA
>  8: 2013-01-23   1040    3      9      NA
>  9: 2013-01-28    415    5      9       0
> 10: 2013-01-31    650    3      9      NA
> 11: 2013-02-04    725    4      9       1
> 12: 2013-02-07    450    3      9      NA
> 13: 2013-02-11    550    4      9       0
> ```

Comment: This one should work, but I recieve yhis error:
Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 231055 rows; more than 197486 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.
Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Apparently, there is more than one game in `matches` which match a line in `data`. (Another case which is not covered by the sample data set). For the time being, please try to add `allow = TRUE`, i.e., `setDT(data)[, winning := setDT(matches)[data[, .(upper = Date, lower = Date - diff)], on = .(Date < upper, Date > lower), allow = TRUE]$winning][]` and see if this works.

Comment: I've noticed that `Date` contains two sequences. Perhaps, there is a hidden parameter which is needed for grouping by?